# Using An API that requires authorization In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, curl

Im using this api that requires authorization. I have the token and the client id so i can make the request on curl easily but I'm trying to make it work in my angular application. The curl command is:

```
curl -H "Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  "https://chitchats.com/api/v1/clients/$CLIENT_ID/shipments"
```

Ive tried doing this on my angular application:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  response:any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){
}
ngOnInit(){
}
searchProd(){
  let headers=new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization','$ACESS_TOKEN')
  this.http.get('https://chitchats.com/api/v1/clients/$CLIENT_ID/shipments', {headers})
  .subscribe((response)=>{
    this.response=response;
    console.log(this.response);
  })
}


}
```

However I get a 403 error when running the application on the browser. Ive had no problems working with other apis that didnt require authorization.

Comment: Hey Travis, welcome to Stack Overflow. What response header information are you seeing? `GET`, `OPTIONS`, etc.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE

Comment: Could be a couple of things: 
1. No access to the resource
2. CORS not configured (use a Chrome plugin to disable CORS client side to check if this is the case: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this way...

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Authorization', '$ACESS_TOKEN');
```

If still not works then allow **cors** from back end.

If you are using **node** as a backend then put this code in `app.js` file.

```
// Allow cross origin permission 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});
```